# How can I output START, END and REPORT Lambda output as JSON?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want the log produced by the java runtime in an AWS lambda function to be in JSON format.

I'm talking about logs like these:

```
2022-07-27T19:30:21.094+03:00   START RequestId: 09e6e95c-5b1f-53c0-8483-b207312166be Version: $LATEST
2022-07-27T19:30:37.640+03:00   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
2022-07-27T19:31:03.536+03:00   END RequestId: 09e6e95c-5b1f-53c0-8483-b207312166be
2022-07-27T19:31:03.536+03:00   REPORT RequestId: 09e6e95c-5b1f-53c0-8483-b207312166be Duration: 42441.58 ms Billed Duration: 42442 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 226 MB
```

Comment: What would JSON for these logs look like beyond `{"timestamp":x, "log":y}`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot alter the format of the START, END, or REPORT log lines. These are produced by the Lambda service.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Lambda, when you write a Java Lambda function, you have two options for logging.

- log4j
- LambdaLogger
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html#java-wt-logging

Add log4j2 propety in your lambda class path

log4j2.properties file to use the JSON Template Layout:

```
       log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
       log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=UTF-8
       log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
       log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern={"debug_level":"%p","debug_timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","debug_thread":"%t","debug_file":"%F", "debug_line":"%L","debug_message":"%m"}%n
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2023, this is possible by changing the Lambda log format from Text to JSON.

The structure of the default lambda output is as follows.

START:

```
{
    "time": "2023-12-14T11:30:52.620Z",
    "type": "platform.start",
    "record": {
        "requestId": "xxx",
        "version": "$LATEST"
    }
}
```

REPORT:

```
{
    "time": "2023-12-14T11:30:52.627Z",
    "type": "platform.report",
    "record": {
        "requestId": "xxx",
        "metrics": {
            "durationMs": 7.083,
            "billedDurationMs": 8,
            "memorySizeMB": 1024,
            "maxMemoryUsedMB": 157
        },
        "status": "success"
    }
}
```

See: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-advanced-logging-controls-for-aws-lambda-functions/

For CDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.LogFormat.html